# facebook-Make "Share" - Button invisible

Tags: facebook

I wonder if it is possible to make the facebook share button invisible. Now it always shows an icon.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,

enne

EDIT: I would like to have a html-div where a user can click on it. This div should include the functionality of a facebook-share button, which means there should happen the same things as if the user would click on the share button. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: why would you want to make it invisible? more context, please. if it's to mislead your users into clicking on it, stackoverflow won't help you.

Comment: Ähm, sry, I want to make a custom Link where a user can click on it. This links should open the dialog which would be opened by the share button by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the Feed dialog if you want the user to click a custom link which triggers a share?

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ for more information

Comment: That's very intersting, I'll mark this as answer. Thanks for the help lgy